# how to use string replacement with golang

Tags: regex, string, go

I am Making a command line tool for sending an email where I am using [urfave/cli](https://github.com/urfave/cli) package from golang
i had made the application where everything is working properly but got stuck with one string replacement part.

Basically, I want to convert a string

> `info@gmail.com,vik@hotmail.com,myemailid@yahoo.com`

to

> "info@gmail.com","vik@hotmail.com","myemailid@yahoo.com"

I tried regex substitution but that didn't give me an accurate result. so I manipulate my code where I used `String.Split` separated by ',' but after that the look around got complex. can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the value, simply run something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := "info@gmail.com,vik@hotmail.com,myemailid@yahoo.com"
    emails := strings.Join(Map(strings.Split(input, ","), func(in string) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, in)
    }), ",")

    fmt.Printf("%v", emails)
}

func Map(vs []string, f func(string) string) []string {
    vsm := make([]string, len(vs))
    for i, v := range vs {
        vsm[i] = f(v)
    }
    return vsm
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/M0xfCkpT6uD

Good luck.

Comment: I have done `strings.Split` but it converts the string to array and then I also tried appending `" "` with comma separate using append but it didn't help I simply want to do append double quotes to the value separated by comma > "indo@gmail.com","vik@yahoo.com","myplace@gmail.com" hope you got my need

Comment: I'll update with a solution, I understand what you're trying to do now.

Comment: Solution added, please let me know if this does what you need. If so, please ✔ Accept the answer :)